# Prevent Test Utility Execution Outside of Running Tests

Tags: apex, unit-test

I've written a test utility class, `TestUtil` that looks a bit like below:

```
public class TestUtil {
   /**
    * Custom exception class.
    *
    * @return TestUtilException
    */
    public class TestUtilException extends Exception {}

   /**
    * Creates a list of Account records for testing.
    *
    * @param  Integer count
    * @return List<Account>
    */
    public List<Account> CreateAccounts(Integer count) {
        List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            accountList.add(new Account(
                Name = 'Foo Bar ' + i
            ));
        }

        return accountList;
    }

   /**
    * Constructor.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public TestUtil()
    {
        if (!Test.isRunningTest())
        {
            throw new TestUtilException('Methods can only be used in running unit tests.');
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do is add some kind of protection against accidentally flooding an environment with nonsense data, hence the custom exception and the check in the constructor.

However, I can't exactly test for this. The line with the thrown exception...

```
throw new TestUtilException('Methods can only be used in running unit tests.');
```

... can never be covered because in unit testing, it will always be running in a unit test.

Is there a better way to handle this, or shall I have to deal with < 100% code coverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want 100% coverage, go with an assertion:

```
public TestUtil() {
    System.assert(Test.isRunningTest(), 'Methods can only be used in running unit tests.');
}
```

This will pass when running tests, but cause a failed assertion when not. Mind you, you don't get a catchable exception, but it will ensure the class can't be used outside of tests.

Also, I'd recommend doing this **statically** in your test to avoid clever programmers working around your limitation:

```
public class TestUtil {
  static {
    System.assert(Test.isRunningTest(), 'Methods can only be used in running unit tests.');
  }
}
```

This will prevent developers from getting clever by doing something like this:

```
TestUtil u = (TestUtil)JSON.deserialize('{}', TestUtil.class);
```

---

If you still want the exception, you could change to a static variable:

```
@testVisible private static Boolean isTesting = Test.isRunningTest();
public TestUtil()
{
    if (!isTesting)
    {
        throw new TestUtilException('Methods can only be used in running unit tests.');
    }
}
```

Then, you can test it!

```
@isTest static void testTestUtil() {
    TestUtil.isTesting = false;
    try {
      TestUtil t = new TestUtil();
      System.assert(false, 'Expected exception');
    } catch(TestUtil.TestUtilException e) {
    }
 }
```

We make it `private` and `@testVisible` to prevent access from non-unit tests reaching in and setting isTesting to true.

---

Finally, as a compilation limitation, go ahead and just make everything `private` and `@testVisible`:

```
@isTest @testVisible private class TestUtil {
```

This will cause non-unit tests to not compile at all, eliminating the need to use the constructor, exception, etc.

Comment: I didn't expect I could be so versatile with this, thanks for this sir!

Comment: @DanJones That's the beauty of programming; there's usually more than one way to solve a problem. Glad I could help! You'll find the static variable method useful for other forms of testing, too, so remember it.